# Convert png string to image file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a png as a string looking like this:

```
"89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 000000b6 00000067 08020000"
```

around 100 000 characters.

How do i convert that in to a png file?

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces, convert the hexa-decimal representation to a binary sequence using [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack).

```
bin_seq = ["89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 ....".gsub(' ', '')].pack('H*')
# => "\x89PNG\x00\xD0\xA1\xA0\xA0\x00\x00\x00\r\x04\x94\x84E..."
```

Then write it to a file.

```
IO.write('/path/to/a_image_file.png', bin_seq, {mode: 'wb'})
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the spaces before packing.